# Selector function called from another class

Tags: objective-c, callback, performselector

I have a viewController `Controller` and a view `view A`. Also `ViewA` contains a button.
Generally, we call a function in the same class to be executed when clicked on button. But I want a method in `controller` to be executed when clicked on button.

Following are the two methods I have worked out:

```
//method 1 
//UIView A
-(id)initWithSelector:(SEL)callbackInB withDelegate:(id)delagateB
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
         delegate = delegateB;
         myCB = callbackInB;
    }
    return self;
}
//somewhere in UIView A
[btn addTarget:delegate action:myCB forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This works fine .But instead of this if I do as second method , it shows "perform selector may leak as the selector function is unknown" .

```
//method 2
//somewhere in UIView A 
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)btnPressed:(id)sender
{

    if([delegate respondsToSelector:myCB])
        [delegate performSelector:myCB];

}
```

Comment: delete [btn addTarget:delegate action:myCB forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; string. [delegate performSelector:myCB] called to myCB action

Comment: so you are asking about two different things? 1) the "perform selector may leak as the selector function is unknown" compiler warning when you compile it, and 2) your program crashes when run? At least give some stack trace or some information about the crash if it actually crashes.

Comment: @newacct : the program does not crash now , but why does the warning popsup??

Comment: @CodeJack will you post the the selector you get from other class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks are the answer to this problem:

Class B

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^myBlock)(void);

 -(id)initWithMyBlock:(void(^)(void))block
 {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
         self.myBlock = block;
    }
     return self;
 }

[btn addTarget:delegate action:@selector(btnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)btnPressed {
  if (_myBlock) {
    _myBlock();
  }
}
```

Just watch out for retain cycles

Comment: agreed , but what is the problem in my code ? why does it crash ??